# Performing row operations on ActiveRecord objects prior to an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to calculate a weighted average of a variable in my model based on a second variable in my model and I'm having trouble finding a way to do it through ActiveRecord.

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :number_of_employees, :average_age

  def self.wt_avg_age
    #return sum(number_of_employee * average_age)/sum(number_of_employees)
  end
end
```

In straight SQL, I would use:

```
SELECT id, SUM(number_of_employees*average_age)/SUM(number_of_employees) 
FROM employer
GROUP BY name
```

Can I execute something like this on an ActiveRecord relation in an eloquent way (i.e., without pulling down separate arrays and iterating through every record to get my numerator)? I have tried different combinations using .select(), .pluck(), and sum() without any luck. I'm having trouble getting the ActiveRecord object to perform the sumproduct.

Comment: Why do you want to use the object model where simple sql query would do? use right tools for the job.

Comment: `id` is unique. If you group by `id`, you wouldn't really be accomplishing anything - it'd be equivalent to `SELECT number_of_employees * average_age / number_of_employees FROM employer`.  Is there something else you would group on perhaps, or is this supposed to be a single row result?

Comment: I made up the example so I overlooked this. I'm grouping by name now. I should be returning one record for each name.

Comment: Sergio- Point taken. I'm a bit new to Rails so I was just wondering if I'm overlooking some construct to do this without dipping into SQL. My preference would be to use SQL everywhere but I'm learning and attempting to apply ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
Employer.select("name, (SUM(number_of_employees*average_age)/SUM(number_of_employees)) as sum").group(:name)
```

That will return Employer instances to you, but they will only have the .name and .sum attributes on them. This will run the exact SQL query that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum` takes a block:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb, line 92
def sum(*args)
  if block_given?
    self.to_a.sum(*args) {|*block_args| yield(*block_args)}
  else
    calculate(:sum, *args)
  end
end
```

(also see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum)

So you might try:

```
def self.wt_avg_age
  numerator = self.all.sum { |e| e.number_of_employee * e.average_age }
  denominator = self.sum :number_of_employees
  return numerator / denominator
end
```

Comment: On second thought, this doesn't give me the option to group by name so it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Be careful this will do the calculation in ruby-land not via SQL

Answer (score 0):

Take a try, maybe it can works:

```
def self.wt_avg_age
  a = Employer.sum("number_of_employee * average_age")
  b = Employer.sum('number_of_employees')
  a/b
end
```